# is there anyway to use ServiceProvider.GetService() with reflection in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Here is my class.

```cs
public class DemoJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public DemoJob(ILogger<SecondJob> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.JobDetail.JobType.FullName);
            logger.LogError(context.JobDetail.JobType.FullName);
        });
    }
}
```

I want to get all service of one class's dependency injection.
I could use like

```cs
var service = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DemoJob))
```

it seems all right.
But now I want to use it with reflection,like

```cs
var jobType = assembly.GetType("xxxx.SecondJob")
var service = serviceProvider.GetService(jobType)
```

`service` always returns a null value.
Is there anyway?

Comment: In the last code snippet, I suppose you mean `serviceProvider.GetService(jobType);`?

Comment: @KevinGosse yeah,my mistake,let me edit it.

Comment: Show how you register `SecondJob`

Comment: @mtkachenko   `services.AddSingleton<SecondJob>();` in Startup.cs

Comment: There really shouldn't be any difference between using `typeof` or getting an instance of Type through reflection. If you're sure the registration is correct, I can think of two possibilities: either `assembly.GetType` fails (check that `jobType` isn't null), or `assembly` is actually loaded in a different appdomain (or possibly a different AssemblyContext, I don't know if types can be shared across contexts). Where do `assembly` comes from?

Comment: One test you can do is checking whether `typeof(SecondJob) == jobType` is true

Comment: @KevinGosse I agree with you.But in my case,there is actually different between typeof and GetType,even I create an instant of DemoJob and try GetService of jobInstant,is still returns null.Just use GetService(typeof(DemoJob)),I can get services i registed.

Comment: @KevinGosse returns false

Comment: So the problem isn't ServiceProvider but why the two types don't match. Where does `assembly` come from?

Comment: Instead of `assembly.GetType("xxxx.SecondJob")`, can you try `Type.GetType(""xxxx.SecondJob, NameOfTheAssemblyThatContainsSecondJob")`?

Comment: @KevinGosse it's my dll,`Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "xxx.dll");`

Comment: Ok, so it's an AssemblyContext issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading   (see "Avoid Loading an Assembly into Multiple Contexts")

Comment: @KevinGosse use `var jobType = Type.GetType($"xxx.DemoJob, {assembly.FullName}");` solved my question,thank you Kevin.^o^

Answer (score 1):

In this case,you can use Type.GetType() instead of someType.GetType().Helped me solve the question.Thanks to @KevinGosse